# Change private keys of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-key, public-key, key-pair

I have two servers (instances) with private keys, I want to change those keys without stopping the servers (instances) or creating new ones.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add or replace a key pair for your instance: [Amazon EC2 key pairs and Linux instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-key-pair)

Also, have a look at the following guide. It describes a case where the initial key pair had been lost but—if I understand your question—should also be applicable to your situation: [Connect to an Amazon EC2 Instance When the SSH Key Pair Is Lost](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/)

Comment: thank you alot, It solved my problem, I have the keys and now I replaced it by accessing ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and I add generated key by puTTygen and all done .

Comment: there is a nice video in youtube also helped me : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDa6YzFzeNY&t=42s